# React / span with onClick event not in tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

Something out of my knowledge is happening in my code. I have a component which renders a span tag with a onClick event:

```
<span style={styles.cursorPointer} onClick={this.handleClick}>{props.page.word}</span>
```

But when I check the code in the browser the span tag doesn't have the onClick:

[developer tools screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHJUv.png)

I know it seems a little abstract but I just can't figure why the onClick isn't there.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the **onClick** works ? Maybe during the transpilation JSX to JS, the onClick is managed in pure javascript...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing JSX with html. The span tag you have in your code is not plain html tag it is a javascript object(read more about jsx [here](https://jsx.github.io/)). React takes care of binding the events for you, don't worry if you can't see onClick in your html.

Comment: You are right. I'm confusing it. Then it means I have a binding event problem because it is not triggering the event. Thanks

Comment: I've just placed a console.log inside the event and every time I clicked in the span tag it does triggers the event, so it should be another issue with what I want to toogle on and off. Thanks again